# Check if value was greater than x for y consecutive months period in changes history

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have table with members level changes. It has historical changes of level of all members and date when change happened. For example I can list changes for member number 5:

```
select * from memberlevelhistory where member = 5
```

result:

```
member  changedate  level
5       2012-04-01  2
5       2012-03-01  3
5       2012-02-01  2
5       2011-02-01  6
5       2011-02-01  6
5       2010-03-15  6
5       2010-02-01  5
5       2010-01-01  5
5       2009-10-01  4
5       2009-08-27  2
5       2009-08-01  1
```

Last entry in history table is current level.

QUESTION:
How to list all members that had level higher or equal to 3 for period of 3 months or more ?

That is a simplified version of the question. To make it even more fun I need only members that didn't drop below the starting level during this 3 month period. So if a member started the 3 month period with level 4 and is only level 3 on the last month then that member is excluded from the list.

Any help, even with the simplified question is much appreciated.

EXTENDED VERSION:

I also need this period of >=3 months of level >=3 happen inside last 6 months window.

Comment: the three months starts from the date of the first level?

Comment: @John Woo: No, I need to search if there is any 3 months period with level >= 3 in member history

Comment: @rumburak from the last `changedate` you want to check 3 months before if the level is `>= 3`? is that what you mean?

Comment: @Derek Floss: I want member to be listed if there was any 3 consecutive months period with level >= 3 in this member history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a case for `not exists`. An entry is valid if there is not another entry with level less than currently selected record in next three months. This solves both requirements. There might be an issue with last entry per member where level is appropriate, but span is not known. I've decided to remove those records, but you might have other ideas.

[Sql Fiddle with example is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d22bd/1).

```
select distinct mlh.member
  from memberlevelhistory mlh
 where mlh.level >= 3
   and not exists
       (
         select null
           from memberlevelhistory mlh2
          where mlh2.member = mlh.member
            and mlh2.changedate >= mlh.changedate
            and mlh2.changedate < dateadd(month, 3, mlh.changedate)
            and mlh2.level < mlh.level
       )
    -- The last entry might have appropriate level
    -- But we cannot tell how long it lasted,
    -- So we are going to remove it.
   and exists
       (
         select null
           from memberlevelhistory mlh3
          where mlh3.member = mlh.member
            and mlh3.changedate > mlh.changedate
       )
```

EDIT:

I have rewritten not exists() to left join and added 'last entry lasting until today' criterion.

[Sql Fiddle with example is here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44bea/1)

```
select distinct mlh.member
  from memberlevelhistory mlh
  left join memberlevelhistory mlh2
    on mlh2.member = mlh.member
   and mlh2.changedate >= mlh.changedate
   and mlh2.changedate < dateadd(month, 3, mlh.changedate)
   and mlh2.level < mlh.level
 where mlh.level >= 3
   and mlh2.member is null
   and datediff(month, mlh.changedate, getdate()) >= 3
```

**Query rewritten:**

```
; with ranges as 
(
  select mlh.member, mlh.changedate StartRange, min(isnull(mlh2.changedate, getdate())) EndDate
    from memberlevelhistory mlh
    left join memberlevelhistory mlh2
      on mlh2.member = mlh.member
     and mlh2.changedate >= mlh.changedate
     and mlh2.level < mlh.level
   where mlh.level >= 3
  group by mlh.member, mlh.changedate
 having datediff (month, min(isnull(mlh2.changedate, getdate())), getdate()) <= 6
    and datediff (month, mlh.changedate, min(isnull(mlh2.changedate, getdate()))) >= 3
)
select distinct member
  from ranges
```

[And Sql Fiddle is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31f91/15).

I believe that 100 and 101 should be included because both had a good run for 3 months and this was on in march which is six months before this moment.

What I did is to generate ranges when somebody had a good run, and then test this ranges for duration of 3 months or more and ending date in last six months.

**UPDATE**: if I finally got it right, you need that *duration* is lasting for three months in last six months. To calculate that one might truncate changedates to current date - six months. Using that as starting point, and finding ending point of a range as first `mlh` having lower level and higher date as ending point one has enough information to calculate duration.

```
; with ranges as 
(
  select mlh.member, 
  -- If good range starts more than six months before today
  -- truncate it to today - 6 months
         case when datediff (month, mlh.changedate, getdate()) > 6
              then dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
              else mlh.changedate 
              end StartRange,
  -- First bad mlh after current changedate
         min(isnull(mlh2.changedate, getdate())) EndRange
    from memberlevelhistory mlh
    left join memberlevelhistory mlh2
      on mlh2.member = mlh.member
     and mlh2.changedate >= mlh.changedate
     and mlh2.level < mlh.level
   where mlh.level >= 3
  group by mlh.member, mlh.changedate
  -- As above, limit good range to max six months before today
  -- And only get those lasting at least three months
 having datediff (month, case when datediff(month, mlh.changedate, getdate()) > 6
                              then dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
                              else mlh.changedate 
                          end, 
                         min(isnull(mlh2.changedate, getdate()))) >= 3
)
select distinct member
  from ranges
```

[Sql Fiddle with example is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31f91/43).

Comment: @rumburak If your (deleted) comment about last entry lasting until today is still valid, you might remove `and exists` and add `and datediff(month, mlh.changedate, getdate()) >= 3`. Please take a look at [another Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44bea/1) where I have rewritten not exists() to left join and added this criterion. Member 3 (last line in left panel) will appear if you change the year to 2012.

Comment: Tnx Nikola. This code is brilliant. However I need one more criterion and that is 'during last 6 months' so same thing but this 3 months period need to be in last 6 months. Is this an easy one or should I create another question for that?

Comment: @rumburak If I understood you correctly, you need to replace all occurrences of `3` with `6`. You might want to parameterize the query in order to simplify future requirements - I'll add a query in two minutes.

Comment: @rumburak I wasn't being very careful when I said "all occurrences". level >= 3 should not be changed. Please see `EDIT 2` section.

Comment: No Nikola :) I need to add one more thing. So it would be like 'any user with level >=3 during 3 consecutive months that happend during last 6 months'

Comment: @rumburak :-D silly me. Are you looking for start of the period to be in last 6 months or any changedate in last 6 months will do?

Comment: @ Nikola: None of the above I think. Eg.: on 01.01.2012 member reached level 3 and on 01.05.2012 member is back to level 2, so member has 3 months period of level >=3 in history but should not be listed because there is no 3 months period of level >=3 in last 6 months history of this member.

Comment: @rumburak Query returns all mlh's with level 3 or above who did not have a drop in next three months. If you further narrow them to ones from last six months, you will effectively remove people who got to this high status six months before. To do this replace last datediff with `and datediff(month, mlh.changedate, getdate()) between 3 and 6`. [Sql Fiddlehere](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb271/1).

Comment: @ Nikola: [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31f91/1) in this case 1, 2, 3, 4 should be listed

Comment: @rumburak Please check last section of my answer.

Comment: @ Nikola: 100 and 101 should not be listed, because this period need to be inside last 6 months, they do not have 3 required months with level >= 3 during last 6 months

Comment: @rumburak My apologies for the delay, I wish we finished this earlier. Please check last update.

Comment: @ Nikola: No worries. Marvelous code. I modified it on my own exactly the same way just with '>= 6' instead of '> 6' :) but it should be the same in this case. I was just worried about [this close to end of month dates](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aac15/1), but in my business case its fine. I hope I can meet You some day because I own You big beer. Tnx Nikola.

Comment: @rumburak Great news. And sure looking forward to this beer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT MEMBER, CHANGEDATE, LEVEL, COUNT(LEVEL) AS COUNT
  FROM MEMBERLEVELHISTORY
  GROUP BY MEMBER, CHANGEDATE, LEVEL)
WHERE LEVEL >= 3
AND COUNT >= 3;
```

This should help you our for the simplified version, in order to group results consecutively is beyond me though!